# Get handle to previouly active window where my application may be a tray app or not in focus

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I need to get the handle to the current/previously active window on my desktop. Basically I am working on a c# Windows Forms application that can take screen shots.
I am using the GetForegroundWindow PInvoke to get this handle, but if I call my code from a menu click, the active window seems to be set to that of the menu itself so the image produced is a small black rectangle.

The application runs in the systray with a context menu. I have also implemented global hot keys and these work fine, but when I use the context menu with the mouse, the above scenario happens.

How to I keep track of the previously active window handle? Bear in mind my application runs as a tray icon so overriding wndproc never fires. I have tried a NativeForm and MessageOnly form  also, but these never fire unless the application has focus.

Are we down to global hooks and external dll's?  Surely there has to be a simple way to solve this issue?  (any yes, I do need to implement menu items as well as keyboard shortcuts for a particular usability scenario.

So, how do I keep track of the current / previous active window on my desktop from a c# app that has no window itself and has no focus?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: What kind of menu do you use? a `ContextMenuStrip`?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you use `ContextMenuStrip` for your tray menu:

```
IntPtr lastHandle;
public IntPtr GetForegroundWin(){
   IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
   if(hwnd != contextMenuStrip1.Handle) lastHandle = hwnd; 
   return lastHandle;      
}
//Add a timer
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 1;
t.Tick += (s,e) => {
    GetForegroundWin();
};//Then you can get the foreground Handle by lastHandle
t.Start();//this timer will run as long as your application runs.
```

OK, without using timer, we still have another choice using `SetWinEventHook`. This function can help you hook some callback to catch some events including `active window change` event. Here is the link for you to learn more: [Detect active window changed using C# without polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372055/detect-active-window-changed-using-c-sharp-without-polling)

Here is the code for the solution without using timer (polling):

```
//Must add using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(int minEvent, int maxEvent, IntPtr hModule, WinEventProcDelegate proc, int procId, int threadId, int flags);
    private delegate void WinEventProcDelegate(IntPtr hHook, int ev, IntPtr hwnd, int objectId, int childId, int eventThread, int eventTime);
    private void WinEventProc(IntPtr hHook, int ev, IntPtr hwnd, int objectId, int childId, int eventThread, int eventTime)
    {
        if(hwnd != contextMenuStrip1.Handle) lastHandle = hwnd;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        //EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3
        //WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0
        SetWinEventHook(3, 3, IntPtr.Zero, WinEventProc, 0, 0, 0);                                                                      
    }
    IntPtr lastHandle;
}
//You can access the lastHandle to get the current active/foreground window. This doesn't require GetForegroundWindow()
```

Comment: Hi KK< I am using a ContextMenuStrip for my tray menu. I have tried your code in it's menu_click event but it still doesn't work.  Can you tie your solution together for me? How and Where would I use your GetForegroundWin() method ?

Comment: @user2026382 whenever you need to get the `Handle` of the foreground window you can call the method `GetForegroundWin` instead of the method `GetForegroundWindow`. The return `Handle` will be of the foreground window except the ContextMenuStrip window.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing but its not working. I just tried it in the traymenu opening event, and even then its not working. Lets say I have notepad open for example, I click on notepad and its now the active window. But as soon as I click on my tray app, notepad loses focus, its no longer the active window. I am using your method and passing lasthandle into my screen capture method, but I still get back a small back rectangle as the image.

Comment: @user2026382 you may need a timer to check the foreground window, see my updated code.

Comment: Oh lord I don't want to start using a timer, hammering my app every millisecond or whatever, there has to be a better solution. I just need to know what was the last active window before I clicked on my tray icon.

Comment: @user2026382 I've written an application of this kind (not snapshot but had also to track the last active window) and I also used a timer, it worked OK. The `GetForegroundWindow()` doesn't consume much calculation. There won't any other solution if you stick to `GetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: Your last sentence suggests there are alternatives to GetForegroundWindow ??  Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: @user2026382 not really, I don't know other choices, in fact we have to be notified if the active/foreground window is changed (some kind of event) but we don't have such event. That's why we have to `probe` to update the last active window using `GetForegroundWindow`. `Win32` doesn't supports `event`. There is another choice for you is `hook into system globally`, however it's not easy to do (even using some library like `EasyHook`) and it's also expensive in slowing down the system performance (a bit or very slightly but it does affect).

Comment: @user2026382 I've found a helpful link for you, it would be the choice you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a much simpler solution and while it's a bit of a hack, it works beautifully, reliably and costs nothing.  What I do is, from my menu click event, I show a form, then immediately hide the form. This has the effect of taking focus away from the taskbar back to the desktop. I show my form, then when I close it, the previously selected window regains its focus. Then my GetForegroundWindow gets it's handle.

My app, actually has a status form that can update the user during lengthy processes, so I can show it with a "capturing, please wait" message or something. Or I can simply flash it up on screen so fast that it cannot be really seen at all. Then I close it, thread sleep(100) and carry on with the screen capture.  Works like a charm

```
        if (_runMode == RunMode.Tray)
        {
            FormStatus f = new FormStatus();
            f.Show();
            f.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        ScreenCapture.CaptureActiveWindow(filename);
```