# Performance cost of SetWinEventHook vs Polling in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, hook, polling

I am developing a time tracking application, it monitors window changes and user idleness.
My question is: which one costs more in terms of performance, wasting system resources:

- using SetWinEventHook (EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND),
- or setting a Timer.Tick and check if the active window title changed user32.dll GetForegroundWindow() and GetWindowText() all the time) ?

For testing user idleness I already figured out that using low level mouse and keyboard hooks are more expensive than calling GetLastInputInfo() with a Timer. (or am I doing something wrong?)
I used these sources for the keyboard and mouse hooks: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/
and for the window change hooks:
[Detect active window changed using C# without polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372055/detect-active-window-changed-using-c-sharp-without-polling)

Thanks!